# trying to remove php unset array but not working

Tags: php

I am trying to remove 3rd array but it is not working.
function is returning all the arrays.

```
function edit_class_columns() {
    $columns = array(
        'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title'     => __( 'Name', '' ),
        'added_by'  => __( 'Added By', '' ),
        'locations' => __( 'Locations', '' ),
        'date'      => __( 'Date', '' )
    );

    unset($columns[3]);
 // return $columns;
    print_r($columns);

}
```

Comment: what is `__('Name','')` for ?

Comment: array doesnt have `key 3`...

Comment: unset($columns['locations']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 unset($columns['locations']);
```

Comment: Ahh i am continuously working since last night. and my mind is sucked.
Thanks for showing me right path.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the array's key  in unset, in this case, there is no  `$columns[3]`, You must do:

```
unset($columns['locations'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array doesn't have an element with index 3! But if you want to delete the 3rd column you can do this:

```
unset($columns["locations"]);
```

OR if you still want to use `unset($columns[3]);` you can do this:

```
unset($columns[array_keys($columns)[3]]);
```